# Blackbody Radiation vs Emission Line spectrum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, photon-emission

A perfect blackbody has a predicable emission pattern in terms of both intensity and color, given by Planck´s law.

Similarly, elements such as Hydrogen or Helium will emit specific wavelengths when an electron transitions between different energy levels. For the Hydrogen atom, strictly in the visible domain, the [Balmer series][1] gives those colors.

Now lets consider an accretion disk around a black hole. The core question i have is if the Blackbody radiation given off by the disk will always dominate over the Emission lines, to the point where an inclusion of such lines on the mathematical side is negligible?

Looking at stars, they clearly follow Planck´s law when it comes to color and brightness. So it seems for these Stellar phenomena the Balmer series colors are not worth considering. However, i cant help but feel the strong electromagnetic fields within and especially towards the inner edge of an accretion disk, should have something to say about this.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification. Stars are not actually black bodies and amateurs can do spectroscopy on star light. For the higher magnitude stars, all that is needed, besides good seeing, is a transmission diffraction grating, a camera (e.g., DSLR) and some free (or inexpensive) software to process acquired spectra.